# Pascal , generate a string of numbers

Tags: loops, pascal

I have a problem in pascal : Generate first n numbers in the next sequence: 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,... I wrote a code for these, but the problem is that it doesn't works how i want to.

```
var
s,c: string;
n,i,j: integer;
begin
 s:='';
 readln(n);
 begin
  for i := 1 to n do
   begin
    if ( length(s)/2 -1 >= n) then
    begin
     Break;
    end;
    for j := 1 to i + 1 do
    begin
     str(i,c);
     s:= s + c+',';
    end;

 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that is shorter, and also removes the extra comma at the end: It's a full console program (and adds a prompt for the number of elements):

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  i, j: Integer;
  s: string;
  nItems: Integer;
begin
  s := '';
  Write('Enter # of elements: ');
  ReadLn(nItems);
  for i := 1 to nItems do
    for j := 1 to i + 1 do
    begin
      s := s + IntToStr(i) + ',';
    end;
  System.Delete(s, Length(s), 1); { Remove final comma )
  WriteLn(s);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my question, here is the correct code, it would be nice if you could improve it.

```
var
s,c: string;
n,i,j: integer;
begin
 s:='';
 readln(n);
 begin
  for i := 1 to n do
   begin

    for j := 1 to i + 1 do
    begin
     if ( length(s) > n*2  ) then
    begin
     Break;
    end;
     str(i,c);
     s:= s + c+',';
    end;

   end;
  end;
 Delete(s,length(s)-2,length(s));
 write(s);
 readln;
 end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the way your outer loop works, so `i` indicates at which position you are, and introduce a second number `element`, that represents the current element. Then increment `element` whenever the inner loop has run its course.

```
s:='';
readln(n);
element:=1;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    for j := 1 to i + 1 do
    begin
     str(element,c);
     s:= s + c+',';
    end;
    element:=element+1;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your inner loop:

```
    for j := 1 to i + 1 do
    begin
     if ( length(s) > n*2  ) then
    begin
     Break;
    end;
     str(i,c);
     s:= s + c+',';
    end;
```

Firstly, I'd advise you to always indent for clarity, so

```
    for j := 1 to i + 1 do
    begin
     if ( length(s) > n*2  ) then
       begin
        Break;
       end;
     str(i,c);
     s:= s + c+',';
    end;
```

secondly, you only need `begin` and `end` to turn multiple statements into a single statement, 
so since you've only got `break` in there, they're redundant - just use break directly:

```
    for j := 1 to i + 1 do
    begin
     if ( length(s) > n*2  ) then Break;
     str(i,c);
     s:= s + c+',';
    end;
```

Next, notice that you're recalculating that `c` an awful lot:

```
    str(i,c);
    suffix = c + ',';
    for j := 1 to i + 1 do
    begin
     if ( length(s) > n*2  ) then Break;
     s:= s + suffix;
    end;
```

I'm not all that keen on using break because it feels suspiciously like a goto,
so maybe you could change this into a `repeat ... until` block:

```
    str(i,c);
    suffix = c + ',';
    j := 1;
    repeat 
      s := s + suffix;
      j := j + 1;
    until (j > i+1) or (length (s) > n*2);
```

(Notice that `repeat` and `until` come with an implicit `begin` and `end` so you don't need to type them.)
Now you might argue that I've reduced the clarity by making it less obvious that the loop just increments `j`.
I don't feel strongly in this case whatever you prefer, but if you're using break a lot, consider whether `while` or `repeat` are better for you.

Your condition about `length (s) > n*2` puzzles me (and no-one else has put it in their version of your code).
You seem to want to cut it short for some reason. Are you sure? I'm not.
Below is a table of the output you get without the limit, then the first n*2 items of the output, and the first n*2 
characters of the string, so you can check. What was the `break` statement designed to do?

```
n:      1
output: 1,1
length: 2
n*2:    2
first n*2 numbers:    1,1
first n*2 characters: 1,

n:      2
output: 1,1,2,2,2
length: 5
n*2:    4
first n*2 numbers:    1,1,2,2
first n*2 characters: 1,1,

n:      3
output: 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3
length: 9
n*2:    6
first n*2 numbers:    1,1,2,2,2,3
first n*2 characters: 1,1,2,

n:      4
output: 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4
length: 14
n*2:    8
first n*2 numbers:    1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
first n*2 characters: 1,1,2,2,

n:      5
output: 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5
length: 20
n*2:    10
first n*2 numbers:    1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4
first n*2 characters: 1,1,2,2,2,

n:      6
output: 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
length: 27
n*2:    12
first n*2 numbers:    1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4
first n*2 characters: 1,1,2,2,2,3,
```